# how to minimize multiple subqueries?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have the following query that is a bit slow, as you can see there are a couple of nested queries in the where clause, can anyone come up with a better solution?

```
SELECT m.briefmedialist, 
       Count(DISTINCT s.value) AS selected, 
       m.briefmedialistid 
FROM   vwmedialistmediachannels m 
       LEFT JOIN sessionfilters s 
              ON s.field = 'Media' 
                 AND m.briefmedialistid = s.value 
                 AND s.sessionid = @SessionID 
WHERE  m.id = (SELECT d.briefid 
               FROM   dashboards d 
               WHERE  d.dashboardguid IN (SELECT value 
                                          FROM   sessionfilters s 
                                          WHERE  s.sessionid = @SessionID 
                                                 AND s.field = 'DashboardID')) 
GROUP  BY m.briefmedialist, 
          m.briefmedialistid 
ORDER  BY m.briefmedialist
```

Comment: You can add an index to make the query execute faster

Comment: Could you tell us the structure of the tables involved in the query, the indexes that they have and what exactly is this query trying to produce?

Comment: Are you ***certain*** the sub queries are the source of the performance issue?

Comment: can u use http://www.sqlfiddle.com/ to show the structure of your tables and provide some sample data

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT m.briefmedialist, 
       Count(DISTINCT d.dashboardguid) AS selected, 
       m.briefmedialistid 
  FROM vwmedialistmediachannels m 
  LEFT JOIN sessionfilters s 
    ON s.value = m.briefmedialistid 
   AND s.field = 'Media'
   AND s.sessionid = @SessionID
  JOIN dashboards d
    ON d.briefid = m.id 
  JOIN sessionfilters sf
    ON sf.Value = d.dashboardguid 
   AND sf.field = 'DashboardID'
   AND sf.sessionid = @SessionID
GROUP BY m.briefmedialist, 
         m.briefmedialistid 
ORDER BY m.briefmedialist
```

Similar to Nenad but pulling conditions into the join can sometimes let the query optimizer filter early

Check it out in query optimizer.
Have indexes on the join conditions.
Last resort is to try joins hints (merge, hash, loop).
On complex query the query optimizer will not evaluate join options but I don't think that will be the case here.
If you see all loop joins then try merge on the two sessionfilters joins.

The next step would be to create #temp tables with declared PK for

```
select distinct(s.value)
  from sessionfilters s 
 where s.field = 'Media'
   AND s.sessionid = @SessionID 

select distinct(sf.value)
  from sessionfilters sf
 where sf.sessionid = @SessionID 
   AND sf.field = 'DashboardID'
```

Answer (score 0):

You can easily replace your subqueries with JOINs:

```
SELECT m.briefmedialist, 
       Count(DISTINCT s.value) AS selected, 
       m.briefmedialistid 
FROM   vwmedialistmediachannels m
    INNER JOIN dashboards d ON d.briefid = m.id
    INNER JOIN sessionfilters sd ON sd.VALUE = d.dashboardguid
    LEFT JOIN sessionfilters s  ON s.field = 'Media' 
                AND m.briefmedialistid = s.value 
                AND s.sessionid = @SessionID 
WHERE sd.sessionid = @SessionID 
   AND sd.field = 'DashboardID'
GROUP  BY m.briefmedialist, 
          m.briefmedialistid 
ORDER  BY m.briefmedialist
```

Not sure if that is going to help you much with the performance, as there many other factors we can't see - like indexes, table structure, column types. Also, I guess, that `vwmedialistmediachannels` is a view - so whatever is behind it can be what's slowing the query.